# How to upgrade Vim 7.2 to 7.4 latest on Red Hat 6.6 the easiest way?

Tags: rhel, software-installation, vim

I'm a Vim user, and usually I just install vim via a one liner "apt-get install vim", but for red hat how can I update the 7.2 version to 7.4 with a one liner?

I googled it and many places tell me to compile my own vim 7.4, but i'm really not confident on how this works and where does it even get stored? what is the program files folder equivalent in redhat? why isn't there a one liner to just upgrade to vim 7.4 without having to compile stuff like this.

Comment: First you need to ask yourself "Do I really **need** vim 7.4 because it solves a real problem **I** am having, or do I just **want** it because it's newer and shinier and therefore better than ugly old 7.2?".  sometimes new versions aren't better, or don't do anything new.  and sometimes they solve old bugs but introduce new ones.

Comment: yes i need it for the Gundo plugin which only works with vim 7.3+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in Ubuntu because they ship vim 7.4 on their repositories. It will be that simple on RedHat also if they would have shipped the new version. But, as you have seen, they don't.

RedHat pretty much doesn't upgrade any software to a new major version. This is why redhat6 has a lot of old software (ruby, python, the kernel and almost anything else).

With a little work (not a one liner) you can install vim 7.4.

What you want to do is search first in a site like http://rpm.pbone.net. But this is a little advance for you, I think.

I did the search for you and found this: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/31369581/dir/centos_6/com/vim-enhanced-7.4.629-5.el6.x86_64.rpm.html

From one of those mirrors, you can install directly the package:

```
yum install -y ftp://mirror.switch.ch/pool/4/mirror/centos/6.7/os/x86_64/Packages/vim-enhanced-7.4.629-5.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Off course, this comes with all the caveats of installing software from some random site on internet.

Comment: I suggest grabbing the package from the oracle enterprise linux yum repo that is appropriate for your architecture.  http://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-6.html.  You'll need vim-minimal, vim-enhanced, vim-common, and vim-X11.  Once those four rpm files are downloaded, just issue `rpm -U vim-*.rpm`